# Heroku logs confirm an email is being sent, but emails do not show up in mail box (production only)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, gmail

After submitting a form in the development environment, the application sends an email to my email address. In the production environment, Heroku logs are reporting the email is being sent, but when I check the mailbox the email is not there. Here is my configuration:

**application.yml**

```
GMAIL_USERNAME: "christopherpelnar@gmail.com"
GMAIL_PASSWORD: "sevenmississippi"
```

**user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "christopherpelnar@gmail.com"

  def customer_email(message)
    @message = message
    mail(to: "christopherpelnar@gmail.com", subject: "Message from your website" )
  end

end
```

**messages_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    if @message.save
      UserMailer.customer_email(@message).deliver_now
      redirect_to '/message_sent'
    else
      redirect_to '/'
    end
  end
```

**production.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'stormy-wildwood-29407.herokuapp.com' }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "gmail.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

**Heroku logs**

```
2016-05-22: UserMailer#customer_email: processed outbound mail in 238.2ms
2016-05-22: Sent mail to christopherpelnar@gmail.com (158.2ms)
2016-05-22:
2016-05-22: Date: Sun, 22 May 2016 09:43:29 +0000
2016-05-22: From: christopherpelnar@gmail.com
2016-05-22: To: christopherpelnar@gmail.com
2016-05-22: Message-ID: <17f4181751_3.mail>
2016-05-22: Subject: Message from your website
2016-05-22: Mime-Version: 1.0
2016-05-22: Content-Type: text/html;
2016-05-22:  charset=UTF-8
2016-05-22: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

The problem is only in production and does not have a problem being sent through localhost:3000

Comment: did you set the environment variables on Heroku? Visit this: [Setting Environment Variables on Heroku](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html).

Comment: That solved the issue. I ran `heroku config` in the console and the variables were different from what I have in my application.yml. If you would like to submit this in the form of an answer I would be happy to give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the Heroku's Environment Variables, because after Heroku app is created the environment variables are not setup exactly as in the file **application.yml**. For example, to setup an username you should run in console this command:

```
$ heroku config:add GMAIL_USERNAME=myname@gmail.com
```

More about this can be found here: [Setting Environment Variables on Heroku](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html)

Happy coding! ;)